# $cookies.remove not working for http://localhost/path/#!/

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cookies

A node.js server working on `http://localhost:3000` is setting a cookie for root path (`path: '/'`).

There are two angular apps:

- `http://localhost:3000/#!`
- `http://localhost:3000/admin/#!`

Both apps can see all cookies for `http://localhost:3000` and `path: '/'`.

When using `$cookies.remove(cookieName)` from `http://localhost:3000/#!` app it works fine.

When using `$cookies.remove(cookieName)` from `http://localhost:3000/admin/#!` it doesn't remove the cookie.

Is there any way to remove cookies from sub-path without having to modify the path in server? (I preffer not to do it as both apps share some routes that use cookies).

Comment: Did you try looking at the object returned by the `$cookies.getAll()` function to confirm that the cookie is even set?

Comment: Yes, the cookie is there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the `ngCookies` module assume that all of the cookies you edit will only be attributed to the path that you are currently on and doesn't allow you edit other cookies unless you specifically configure it to do so. If you want to edit a cookie on path `/` from `/admin` You need to add an object in the objects param with a `path` index pointing to the path set in the cookie you wish to remove.

In  your case:

```
$cookies.remove(cookieName, {path: '/'});
```